# How replace text with regular expression in google apps script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

For example I have in google document this numbers *100* *1100* *1000*

How to use the method doc.replaceText() I can find only number 100 and replace him on 200?

```
doc.replaceText('\b100','200');// not work
```

Or I have in google document there is these words  *dogs* *dog* *doggy*

How replace only word dog on cat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know how to use a word boundary, if you just use another word boundary at the end of the string, you will be able to match `100` and `dog`.

```
\bdog\b
\b100\b
```

Note that you need to escape the backslashes:

```
body.replaceText("\\b100\\b", "200");
```

Comment: What is the input and output?

Comment: It works fine: https://regex101.com/r/UBtjxl/1 Unless I misunderstood you. @CrownKing

Comment: @CrownKing Oh I see! You must have forgotten to escape the back slashes! Try `body.replaceText("\\b100\\b", "200"); `